# Why can I not set bpy.context.scene.light_direction?

Tags: light

Trying to set:

```
bpy.context.scene.light_direction = (-0.0796555, 0.0730634, -0.994141)
```

and I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'light_direction'
```

But, when I use the light direction interface sphere shown below, it shows in the info console:

```
bpy.context.scene.light_direction = (0.538462, 0.519231, 0.663671)
```

[image: interface for light direction]

Comment: Try `bpy.context.scene.display.light_direction`. Don't know why the Info window is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's now bpy.context.scene.**display**.light_direction

I don't know when this was changed, or why there's a mismatch between the python in the info pane and the python interface. I was able to find it by tab autocompleting in the python console. Probably worth filing a bug.